# drupal remove unused css

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6

i'm using drupal 6 .Is there any way to remove *unused css* (eg. from system.css) from a page before loading. Unused css degrades my site's performance by increasing loading time.

Comment: How are you determining that there is unused CSS?  Is it because Page Speed or YSlow is complaining?

Comment: ya i found it through Page Speed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would spend more time parsing CSS than you would just loading the file to begin with. You would lose any benefit of the CSS being cached since each page would have a different resulting CSS file. You would be better off simply optimizing and compressing your CSS than trying to parse through it on every page load.

Comment: Just to add to this, since it is correct, make sure you also have decent cache rules in place for text/css (ie, mod_headers and mod_expires stuff) and that Apache is serving up text/css with compression on (ie, mod_deflate stuff).

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. CSS are parsed one time and after cached.

Comment: How is this answer wrong? Do you not understand the original question? I specifically mention that trying to parse out any unused CSS would eliminate the benefits of caching the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

For D7 you can use hook_css_alter

From http://drupalcode.org/project/tao.git/blob/HEAD:/template.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 * @TODO: Once http://drupal.org/node/901062 is resolved, determine whether
 * this can be implemented in the .info file instead.
 *
 * Omitted:
 * - color.css
 * - contextual.css
 * - dashboard.css
 * - field_ui.css
 * - image.css
 * - locale.css
 * - shortcut.css
 * - simpletest.css
 * - toolbar.css
 */
function tao_css_alter(&$css) {
  $exclude = array(
    'misc/vertical-tabs.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/aggregator/aggregator.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/block/block.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/book/book.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/comment/comment.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/dblog/dblog.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/file/file.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/filter/filter.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/forum/forum.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/help/help.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/menu/menu.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/node/node.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/openid/openid.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/poll/poll.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/profile/profile.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/search/search.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/statistics/statistics.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/syslog/syslog.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/admin.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/maintenance.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/system.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/system.admin.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/system.base.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/system.maintenance.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/system.menus.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/system/system.theme.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/tracker/tracker.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/update/update.css' => FALSE,
    'modules/user/user.css' => FALSE,
  );
  $css = array_diff_key($css, $exclude);
}
```

You can also overwrite in theme .info for D6 and now D7 https://drupal.org/node/901062 .

Some theme had developed some helper using .info with and cssexclude key and the hook_css_alter

```
<?php
function twitter_bootstrap_css_alter(&$css) {
  //global $theme_key;
  //$theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', $theme_key);

  $excludes = _twitter_bootstrap_alter(twitter_bootstrap_theme_get_info('exclude'), 'css');
  $css = array_diff_key($css, $excludes);
}

function twitter_bootstrap_js_alter(&$js) {
  $excludes = _twitter_bootstrap_alter(twitter_bootstrap_theme_get_info('exclude'), 'js');
  $js = array_diff_key($js, $excludes);
}

function _twitter_bootstrap_alter($files, $type) {
  $output = array();

  foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($files[$key][$type])) {
      foreach ($files[$key][$type] as $file => $name) {
        $output[$name] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The performance impact is low because hook_css_alter is not run often.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with node js you can also use "find unused css": https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-unused-css

It only supports html files and find out unused css in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the css is unused because the rules are never applied on any page or that you override them in your theme then one solution is to exclude the offending stylesheet altogether and implement the rules that you do want in your theme instead.

There are a few ways to do this, including the [style stripper module](http://drupal.org/project/stylestripper) (which I haven't tried), by unsetting variables in template.php or simplest by copying the system.css file to your theme (and remembering to add to theme.info) and then trimming away to your heart's content.

Additionally if there there are some rarely accessed categories of pages on your site that have rules which are not used elsewhere (e.g. admin pages) you could consider putting these rules in a separate file and conditionally including them from your theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable css file optimization, take a look at "*Administer › Site configuration > Performance*". This will reduce both the size and number of requests made to your website since it will aggregate and compress your css files into a **single file**.

Comment: i'm always use it. the problem is different

Comment: Then you should have been more explicit in your question. And if you really want to remove *unused css* for specific pages, you will have to disable css file optimization.